# Adb server is out of date error

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working on an automation project and Im getting the following error "Adb Server out of date". My OS is ubuntu.  Any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: happened once with my friend and it was because there was another adb in the PATH

Comment: Yeah it was as you said, I had another instance of the ADB installed.